# Bad request error when running aws ec2 instance

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, putty, bad-request, 400-bad-request

I deployed my NLP Flask web app into ec2 instance using putty and it was successfully deployed but when I try to access the file by running main.py and by using the ec2 URL in the browser

```
ec2-17-203-34-83.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
```

I get the below error

```
sign_speak) ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-231:~$ python main.py
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server inst                                                      ead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
 * Running on http://172.31.10.231:8080
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 134-276-929
182.161.22.6 - - [30/Mar/2023 07:22:39] code 400, message Bad request version ('\x02h2\x08http/1.1\x00#\x00\x00\x00')
182.161.22.6 - - [30/Mar/2023 07:22:39] "ü6Âõ¯új¸kî/©�,÷_ùÁFÄl�è�ñ D3�_î�Ù ¡t©Þãåk�jg��KÜ´HòQg}î�æß�çS� zzÀ+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨ÀÀ��/5���3+)ÊÊ �HÓ´£ÁHgÅÈNmÜPU¶äcBoX¶6a2 5*-Dihÿ+
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have an ssl certificate in your flask app.

```
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', ssl_context=('fullchain.pem','privkey.pem'))
```